# How to preserve scope of callback function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, scope

I have a simple function which is member of a class, ImageUtils, that loads an image:

```
this.loadSingleImage = function( path, callbackComplete, callbackFail )
{
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = path;

    img.onload = callbackComplete;
    img.onerror = callbackFail;

    return img;
}
```

I'm trying to understand how to be able to access variables outside the callback function's scope, from within the callback function.  I've read up on call() and apply() but none of it is making sense to me in regards to the function above.  Right now the scope of the callback function is ImageUtils.  I need it to be the same scope as where I called ImageUtils.loadSingleImage().

---

*Edit to provide additional details:*

Consider the following:

```
var Image_Utils = new function()
{
    this.loadSingleImage = function( path, callbackComplete, callbackFail )
    {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = path;
        trace( '   load image: ' + path );

        img.onload = callbackComplete;
        img.onerror = callbackFail;

        return img;
    }
}

var SomeOtherClass = new function()
{
    this.init = function()
    {
        Image_Utils.loadSingleImage( 'somepath', SomeOtherClass.onImageLoaded, SomeOtherClass.onImageFailed );
    }

    this.onImageLoaded = function()
    {
        // console.log( this );
        // returns Img, not SomeOtherClass
        // why?
    }

    this.onImageFailed = function()
    {
        // console.log( this );
        // returns Img, not SomeOtherClass
        // why?
    }
}
```

Comment: function scope depends on where you define the function, not where you call it.

Comment: you can't do it from within the code you've supplied, it would have to be done when you pass in (and/or define) the callback.

Comment: you can memorize arguments and proxy them to the callback using bind(): img.onload = callbackComplete.bind(this, path, img) where the complete function has path and img formal params.

Comment: Sorry guys, without some kind of example your comments aren't registering with me.  I've spent the better part of two days reading up on this and its just not making sense how to structure this.

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Where are the variables that you need to access?

Comment: @Ribs how can we possibly help you pass in `this` context if we don't know what `this` context you want to pass in?

Comment: you need to either pass the variables as arguments to the callback, define the callback inside the loadSingleImage function, or attach all needed props to some globally-reachable object.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see how my question is vague.  I'm asking why when I call ImageUtils.loadSingleImage( 'http://somepath', callbackfunction ); why the scope of 'somecallbackfunction' is ImageUtils, and not the scope of where I called  ImageUtils.loadSingleImage in the first place, and furthermore how to have the scope where ImageUtils.loadSingleImage was called preserved withing the callback function.

Comment: You don't see how it's vague because you know all the details already. We don't. You say the scope of the function is `ImageUtils`, but that doesn't make sense. Is `ImageUtils` a function? Are you talking about scope, or are you talking about the `this` value?

Comment: @Ribs There's a bit of misuse of terms. The **scope** of a function, the variables that it has access to, is determined by where the function is defined and can't change. The **context** of a function, the value of `this`, and its `arguments` are late-bound and determined when the function is called.

Comment: A clear question would include all details needed to replicate the issue with a precise description of what should happen, which in your case appears to be the callbacks having access to certain variables somewhere. Please update your question to fully demonstrate what you need so that we don't need to guess at some of the details.

Comment: wow.. been on this site a long time, answered a lot of questions.. and have never had this kind of sass.  and for the record, I'm an accomplished as3 developer learning JS.  so take it easy on the rhetoric please.

Comment: Sass? All we're doing is asking for clarification. Why does that offend you? Your updated question shows that the issue is entirely different from that which you described. Though you say `console.log( this );` will give you `ImageUtils`, which it will not. It'll give you the `img` element unless there are further details you've excluded.

Comment: ...If you want `this` to be `SomeOtherClass`, then do `SomeOtherClass.onImageLoaded.bind(SomeOtherClass)` when you pass it to `loadSingleImage` *(same for the other function too)*. However, since your description of the output is different from what the output would actually be, there may be other details that would cause this to not work.

Comment: actually I stand corrected on the trace.  Fixing now.  Meant to write Img object.  thanks for pointing that out.  and here's why I am offended: if I knew so well all the correct terms and how to explain what I clearly do not understand why would I even be here asking in the first place?  Ian and Indra got what  iwas getting at just fine.  Someone voted to close this question because I didn;t ask quite right?  Not the spirit of helping I'm used to here.

Comment: No one expects you to know all the correct terms. What is expected is  whether or not you know them, to provide a full and clear example of the issue. That helps to overcome communication gaps. I think you'll get this figured out now, so best of luck to you.

Comment: anyway, not trying to be a jerk, just surprise at how I got jumped all over.  just trying to understand some code, which is why this place exists.  hoping for a solution and thanks in advance for anyone who can help me understand what's going on here.

Comment: ...just to be clear, the heart of the issue is that in JavaScript the value of `this` is not bound by the object that originally held the method. When you pass `object.method` to a function or assign it to a variable, there's no "memory" of that original relationship. The only relationship that counts is that which exists when the method is actually invoked. So `foo.bar()` will set `foo` as the `this` value, but `baz.bar = foo.bar; baz.bar()` will set `baz` as the `this` value. It's all dependent on the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
this.loadSingleImage = function( path, callbackComplete, callbackFail )
  {
  var me = this,
  me.img = new Image();
  me.img.src = path;

  me.img.onload =    callbackComplete.bind(me);
  me.img.onerror = callbackFail.bind(me);

  return img;
  }
```

Comment: Note: jQuery/Zepto/etc. haven't yet been mentioned. You should explain any additional dependencies your answer uses or assume they aren't available to the OP.

Comment: Thank you for attempting to answer my question with what was provided.  I do appreciate it.  Jquery is not an option for my project needs.  I need to use straight JS.

Comment: Then you can use the native bind() method of js

Comment: where the variable "me" is concerned, could I pass in any scope as an argument so something like: this.loadSingleImage = function( path, callbackComplete, callbackFail, scope )
  {
  var me = scope,
....

Comment: Yeah, obviously you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on where you're defining the function/calling it from. Here's a little example of some scoping. I imagine in your example you'll want to access something like the `b` variable.

```
// Global variable
var c = "C";

// Anonymous function. Both b and myFunc are in the same scope
(function() {
   var b = "B";    
   var myFunc= function(a) {
      console.log(a); // logs A which is a parameter
      console.log(b); // logs B as this function is defined in the same scope
      console.log(c); // logs C as this is a global variable
      console.log(d); // logs undefined as it's defined in a different function scope
   };

   myFunc("A");    
})(); 

// Anonymous function. Different scope to the previous one
(function() {
   var d = "D";
})();
```